# Map/Reduce example... is this correct?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, mapreduce

More than once have I seen the following reduce function as a mapreduce usage example for mongodb:

```
function reduce(key, values) {
    var result = {count:0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
}
```

But this strikes me as very odd. The iterating is done with the .forEach() method which uses a callback function to do the counting. However, we *return result;* right away.

Can't it be the case sometimes that we return the result variable before the callback is done iterating through the values?

I thought the purpose of callbacks is that we delegate it to a (possibly) different thread while the main control flow continues normally.

Comment: Callbacks can be used in many different ways.  Some of them are asynchronous.  Many others are not.  `forEach` is not asynchronous.  But note that even when dealing with asynchronous behavior, it's fairly rare that you'll be dealing with multiple threads.  There are growing possibilities for that in the Javascript landscape, but the language has traditionally been single-threaded.

Comment: If callback function confuses you, try replacing `forEach` with simple `for`-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It's not that it confuses me as much as I fail to see the point of synchronous callbacks. I thought the point was to have a more functional programming style with closure features.

Comment: @TiagoEspinha: One reason for such callbacks is to make simpler code.  Loop iteration is often ugly, and that's now buried in the forEach implementation.  And you can pass in a named reference to a function instead of the anonymous function, so if you have, say, `myReusableFunc = function(value) {results.count += value.count}` then you can simply call `values.forEach(myReusableFunc);`, which is extremely clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` isn't asynchronous.
The `return` statement will only be executed after the `forEach` is done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Seems I missed this page in the Javascript book... It does feel a bit pointless to use synchronous callbacks though. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: How else would you execute code in a `forEach`? You'll need the callback to specify a parameter name (like `value` in your example). Also, this way you can just reference a function by name in the callback, and re-use that function in different callbacks.

Comment: The reuse part makes sense, although to me it would make more sense to have a Promise kind of behavior where you specify a second callback to be executed after the forEach is completed. As it is, the return relies on a result that's modified in a callback. Realistically, I only want to return strictly when the forEach has finished and in a pure callback call, it doesn't have to be finished right away if for example, the CPU is busy with other tasks.

Comment: Do you have a link to a example? I don't know that "Promise kind of behavior "

Comment: jQuery implements it, but more than an implementation, from my understanding, it's a way of dealing with this sort of situation. You can find it out here: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: A, I see.
Personally, I don't really see the need for behaviour like that in JavaScript, mostly. (Unless you're talking AJAX requests) Javascript isn't made to manipulate the massive amounts of data that could require asynchronous callbacks, nor does it support multithreading. Besides, it's easier to keep track of where your code's at, in synchronous execution

Comment: @TiagoEspinha:  It would be easy enough to write your own Promise-style `forEach` where each iteration is run after `setTimeout(..., 0)` or `nextTick()`.  I can imagine some use cases for this, but usually `forEach` has been thought of as simply a functional version of loop iteration, with no emphasis on asynchronous behavior.  I don't have many uses that I see now, but if I had one available it might suddenly seem indispensable!